# Why is my regex pattern capturing only final pair? It should capture all pairs in each match

Tags: javascript, regex

My issue is: Why is my regex pattern capturing only final pair? It should capture all pairs in each match.

I have this string here:

```
[Profile0]
Name=Main
IsRelative=1
Path=Profiles/vr10qb8s.default
Default=1

[Profile1]
Name=Clean
IsRelative=1
Path=Profiles/k46wtieb.clean
```

I run this script on it:

```
        var patt = /\[(.*?)\](?:\s+?(.+?)=(.+))+/g;
        var blocks = [];

        var match;
        while (match = patt.exec(readStr)) {
            alert(match)
        }
```

The output of this script is two alerts:

alert 1:

```
Array [ "[Profile0]
Name=Main
IsRelative=1
Path=Profiles/vr10qb8s.default
Default=1", "Profile0", "Default", "1" ]
```

alert 2:

```
Array [ "[Profile1]
Name=Clean
IsRelative=1
Path=Profiles/k46wtieb.clean", "Profile1", "Path", "Profiles/k46wtieb.clean" ]
```

My issue is, why is it only capturing the final pair in each group.

What I was hoping to see was this:

alert 1 SHOULD be (notice the **`"Name", "Main", "IsRelative", "1", "Path", "Profiles/vr10qb8s.default",`**)

```
Array [ "[Profile0]
Name=Main
IsRelative=1
Path=Profiles/vr10qb8s.default
Default=1", "Profile0", "Name", "Main", "IsRelative", "1", "Path", "Profiles/vr10qb8s.default", "Default", "1" ]
```

and alert 2 SHOULD be (notice the **`"Name", "Clean", "IsRelative", "1",`**)

```
Array [ "[Profile1]
Name=Clean
IsRelative=1
Path=Profiles/k46wtieb.clean", "Profile1", "Name", "Clean", "IsRelative", "1", "Path", "Profiles/k46wtieb.clean" ]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sadly, a group with a quantifier does not generate an array of captures for that group. Nor does itautomatically spawn capture groups with increasing numbers.

- For a given group number, the content of the group gets overwritten by the last capture. This is why you are only seeing the last pair.
- The only exception I know is .NET, where you get a CaptureCollection with the successive captures.
- For disambiguation, the branch reset feature in languages such as Perl and PCRE allows you to use the same group on multiple sides of an alternation—again, you do not get multiple captures.

Comment: A very in depth reply thank you man so much this was driving me nuts I couldn't figure out what I was doing wrong. That overwriting things makes a lot of sense. Do you have any recommendations on how to go around this? I was thinking something like: `var patt = /\[(.*?)\](?:\s+?(.+?)=(.+))?(?:\s+?(.+?)=(.+))?/g;` here I just repeating that `(?:\s+?(.+?)=(.+))?` in the pattern two times but for production I'll just repeat it like 20 times, what do you think?

Comment: My first thought would be if it has to execute in the browser. If not, I might run it on the server, where in PHP you may be able to  handle it in one regex using \G. In JS, I would run a regex on each alert separately. Then the regex can just match one single key=value pair, and you iterate through the matches. That's the easiest by far.

Comment: Thanks for that rec. Yeah it has run in the browser :( Would adding the repeated `(?:\s+?(.+?)=(.+))?` be bad for JS performance? Or is it ok?

Comment: No, it's fine. Completely up to you.